# Unmarshalling XML with foreign characters requires entity declarations with Castor

Tags: java, xml, soap, unmarshalling, castor

I have two applications that have to work in conjunction with one another. One is an application I built myself using Java 17, the other is something I have far less control over, one that uses Java 8.

My Java 17 application must take a POJO and marshal it to XML, sending it to the Java 8 application via SOAP. The Java 8 application then receives this XML and unmarshals with Castor into a POJO, and then works on it.

With foreign (non-ASCII) characters, however, all of this falls apart. I have made sure encoding on both sides is set to UTF-8 In the Java 17 application, I use Jakarta/JAXB to marshal to the XML.

```
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PojoClass.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "utf-8");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);
        //marshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.characterEscapeHandler", new NonAsciiEscapeHandler());
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(pojoClassInstance, sw);
        return sw.toString();
```

I have tried adding a separate Character Escape Handler to convert all foreign characters to their hex values. As far as I understand, if non-ASCII characters in XML are in hex, they do not need entity declarations.

In the Java 8 application, however, Castor unmarshals it and Breeze later parses the XML. But unfortunately, as a result, I get the error in com.tbf.xml.XmlObjectFactory: "The entity 'Otilde' was referenced, but not declared." Yes, I know this means that I need to declare it as an XML entity, but *why does it do that when I explicitly send the hex values????* Or if I don't send the hex values, I send the UTF-8 encoded foreign characters which should *NOT* be randomly converted to entities.

Can someone please help me either: 1. Get the Java 8 application with Castor to accept the UTF-8 or hex values and not complain about undeclared entities, or 2. Use the JAXB marshaller in Java 17 to add entity declarations in the generated XML? Thank you!

EDIT: Upon receiving a comment, this is the sample of what appears after turning foreign characters into hex, after the code above (with the NonAsciiCharacterHandler functioning, as in not commented out).

```
<PostalAddr>
    <AddrLine1>&#xd5;888 Sample Rd.</AddrLine1>
    <AddrLine2>&#xc8;021 Apartment 55</AddrLine2>
    <CityNm>&#xf3;Doyle</CityNm>
    <PostalZIPCd>99999</PostalZIPCd>
    <StateProvCd>AK</StateProvCd>
</PostalAddr>
```

This is then turned into a SOAP object and sent via Apache HttpClient.

```
try(CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlMessage, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/soap+xml");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/soap+xml");
            httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
            httpPost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "SOAP");

            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

However, I included a sample here to see what happens when I take the HttpEntity in the same Java 17 application and extract it.

```
HttpEntity entity2 = httpPost.getEntity();
String entityContents = EntityUtils.toString(entity2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And when I do so, this is what the XML shows:

```
<PostalAddr>
    <AddrLine1>Õ888 Sample Rd.</AddrLine1>
    <AddrLine2>È021 Apartment 55</AddrLine2>
    <CityNm>óDoyle</CityNm>
    <PostalZIPCd>99999</PostalZIPCd>
    <StateProvCd>AK</StateProvCd>
</PostalAddr>
```

When unmarshalling in Java 8 with Castor, though, this is what appears:

```
<PostalAddr>
    <AddrLine1>&Otilde;888 Sample Rd.</AddrLine1>
    <AddrLine2>&Egrave;021 Apartment 55</AddrLine2>
    <CityNm>&oacute;Doyle</CityNm>
    <PostalZIPCd>99999</PostalZIPCd>
    <StateProvCd>AK</StateProvCd>
</PostalAddr>
```

This then causes problems down the line when Breeze is used to parse this.

But either way, I believe Castor's unmarshalling is the cause of this discrepancy. I need Castor to not unmarshal it as such, and actually unmarshal with either the hex codes or the actual characters.

Comment: Maybe combine your actual escaping with the `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(String)` from `org.apache.commons:commons-text` library (for escaping String for XML output) after the first so you had in final `&amp;Otilde` which should be unescaped back first to `&Otilde` and then to `Õ` ?

Comment: If the error message says your XML contains an undeclared `&Otilde;` entity reference that can only be because you have one, and if you think you are using hex character references then you're wrong. We can't tell what you have done wrong unless you show us more detail of what you actually did: asserting that you did everything right doesn't help us solve the problem.

Comment: @MichaelKay - I have updated my post to add the sample of what I am trying to send in. Yes, they are written as hex values. I get the same error regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I was finally able to solve this with the help of two of my coworkers.

The problem was that when parsing the XML in Java 8, for whatever reason all foreign characters were being converted to XML entities without any entity declaration. Digging into the Java 8 application - an application that is very old and held together with paperclips and glue - it turns out that the base class of everything the XML was unmarshalled to would run the method `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` (from `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`) on any string element.

```
public void setValue(String s) {
    value = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s);
}
```

However, I could not just get rid of this, as this would break the application.

In the end, @nullpointer's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964506/8858422) of running `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()` turned out to be partially correct. I did not realize I had to add the dependency `org.apache.commons.commons-text` to get the non-deprecated StringEscapeUtils. (Yes, he did mention it, but I accidentally overlooked it. I apologize.)

In my Java 17 application, when marshalling the XML, my `NonAsciiEscapeHandler` class turned out to be useful, but instead of converting all foreign characters to hex, this is instead what I did:

```
// 0x7F is everything above the ASCII plane
if (ch > 0x7F) {
    writer.write(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(String.valueOf(ch)));
    continue;
}
```

This would write the character in unicode. When sent to the Java 8 application, then, the base string element had to be modified. While I still had to keep the `escapeHtml()` method, I modified the `getValue()` method:

```
if(isEscaped(value)) {
    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(value);
} else {
    return value;
}

// etc etc.

private boolean isEscaped(String str) {
    return !str.equals(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str));
}
```

Again, the Java 8 application used `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` while the Java 17 application used `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils`. Thank you everyone for your suggestions and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `escapaJava` method from `StringEscapeUtils` (`org.apache.commons.text`) [or (`org.apache.commons.lang3`) if you're using an older version] when you send it, and call the `unescapaJava` method when you receive it.

If that still does not work, you may want to use `ByteArrayEntity` instead of `StringEntity` in addition to escaping/unescaping.

```
HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(StringUtils.escapeJava(xmlMessage).getBytes(), ContentType.APPLICATION_SOAP_XML);
```

And then read it the same way and unescape it after converting it back to a string.

You may have to try different variations of how to send/receive to get it to work.

Comment: Did you mean ```StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()```? If so, that class is quite deprecated and I would prefer not to use it. I only found ```org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils```, which did not have an escapeJava() method.

Besides, it seems that upon further digging, the problem is likely with Castor in Java 8 unmarshalling the XML.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong class name, yes StringEscapeUtils. It is moved to a different project, commons-text I believe, so you should be able to use it without any issue (Updated the answer). Using the strategy above you can bypass whatever Castor is doing

Comment: Unfortunately, that made it worse. The SAX can no longer parse the XML. I tried both escapeJava and escapeXml - again, the class is deprecated regardless.

Answer (score -1):

If both the sending and the receiving side accepts UTF-8, then you should not have to deal with either escaping non-ascii characters, or using any entitiy declarations.

However, you must make sure that the HTTP body is transferred correctly, using a proper Content-Type, e.g. `Content-Type: application/xml+soap; charset=utf-8`. Note that the default HTTP content encoding is ISO-8859-1 (at least it was the last time I looked).

Comment: Oh yes, I am well aware of encoding. I was dealing with that issue before this, and did manually set Apache HttpClient to UTF-8. As you can see with my edit, I showed the HttpEntity being manually set to UTF-8. At this point, the thing that seems to be causing this issue is Breeze in Java 8, thinking that OTilde is an entity.

Comment: I meant Castor, not Breeze.

Comment: Yes, the entity itself being utf-8, but not the Content-Type. Quoting from your post: 
`httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/soap+xml");` If you can obtain a wire log of the HTTP POST exchange, things might get easier to sort out.

Comment: I updated it to say ```httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");```. I apologize if I misunderstood what you said to do. Regardless, I got the same result.

Comment: Ok. But let's solve this. What version of Castor are you using and in what environment is the Java 8 application deployed?

Comment: Castor looks to be version 1.2. Java 8 is running in a JBoss 7.3.1 environment.